# multiple if else in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a situation where i need to add a class to a div element based on multiple conditions, here i have on level of nesting using ternary operator

```
    <div className={
          typeof this.state.weather.main !== "undefined"
               ? this.state.weather.main.temp > 16
                     ? "app warm"
                     : "app cold"
                : "app"
             }
          >
```

i would like to have something like,

```
         if(this.state.weather.main.temp < 16){
           //add "app cold" class
          } else if(this.state.weather.main.temp > 16){
           //add "app warm" class
          } else if (this.state.weather.main.temp > 35){
             //add "app hot" class
            } else if(this.state.weather.main.temp > 50){
               //add "app extreme" class
             }
             .....
```

and so on

Comment: what is the question? What is the problem? By the way, Since  you are writing  js/ts code you can do whatever you want to do that this languages permit.

Comment: my question is, how to check multiple conditions to add a className to the div, i want to add different className based on temp value here

Comment: @Nag see my edit for the correct approach as what you're currently doing won't work the way you want it.

Comment: @goto1 got it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you move that logic outside of `JSX` and create a method in your component that will return the appropriate styling classes.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
  }
  getElementStyles = () => {
    const { temp } = this.state.weather.main;

    if (temp < 16) {
      return "app cold";
    }
    if (temp > 16) {
      return "app warm";
    }
    if (temp > 35) {
      return "app hot";
    }
    return "app";
  }
  render() {
    const classes = this.getElementStyles();
    return (
      <div className={classes}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, one suggestion I'd like to make is that you need to look at ranges in temperatures rather than seeing if `temp` is less than or more than some number, otherwise you will not get accurate results.

```js
getElementStyles = () => {
  const { temp } = this.state.weather.main;

  if (temp >= 0 && temp < 16) {
    return "app cold";
  }
  if (temp >= 16 && temp < 35) {
    return "app warm";
  }
  if (temp >= 35 && temp < 50) {
    return "app hot";
  }
  if (temp >= 50) {
    return "app extreme";
  }
  return "app";
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably best to have this logic outside of the render method.

You could define a function within your class (or assign a function to a variable if it's in a functional component), for example:

```
getWeatherClass = () => {
     if(this.state.weather.main.temp < 16){
         return "app-cold"
     } else if(...) {
     ...
}
```

And then in your `render` function's JSX:

```
 <div className={this.getWeatherClass()}>
```